# Log4Net not logging in parts of web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I have the following Log4Net code running in my global.asax page. Each of the log statements log successfully to my ado.net appender.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
ILog logger = null;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


    logger.Debug("Application Started");
    logger.Info("Application Started");
    logger.Error("Application Started");
    logger.Fatal("Application Started");

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    logger.Debug("Application Started");
    logger.Info("Application Started");
    logger.Error("Application Started");
    logger.Fatal("Application Started");
}
```

The following code in my controllers will not log anything to the ado.net appender.

```
public class LogSvcController : ApiController
{
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

private EngProjDocSetEventsDBEntities db = new EngProjDocSetEventsDBEntities();

// GET: api/LogSvc
public IQueryable<EngProjDocSetEventsWeb.Models.Log4NetData> GetLogEntries()
{
    logger.Info("Begin GetLogEntries ApiController");

    var top1k = (from l in db.Log4NetData
                 orderby l.Id descending
                 select l).Take(1000);

    return top1k;
}
...
```

I also have Internal Debuging turned on but there is no information indicating a problem.

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
```

I am unable to find much information about the ILog object in the debugger to assist in understanding why it is not logging.

How can I determine the connection string and other information used at the time the log statement is executed in order to find out the problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

If I call the following on the top of the page where logs do not record it works!

```
log4net.Config.XmlConigurator.Configure();
```

Why do I need to call this a second time?  Is this somehow related to WebAPI or MVC?

Answer (score 0):

To see what the connection string is set to, you can examine the log appender at runtime:

```
Hierarchy logHierarchy = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;

 if (logHierarchy == null)
 {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
    "Can't get conn string as hierarchy is null. Has logging been initialised?");
 }

 // This assumes you have at most one AdoNetAppender
 var appender = logHierarchy
                  .GetAppenders()
                  .OfType<AdoNetAppender>()
                  .SingleOrDefault();

 if (appender == null)
 {
   throw new InvalidOperationException(
       "Can't get connection string as can't locate a database appender");
 }

 Console.WriteLine("Connection string: {0}", appender.ConnectionString);
```